# How does current flow through a mono (TS) guitar cable?

Tags: audio, cables, shielding, piezo

My basic understanding of electronics says there must be a complete circuit for electricity to flow, so does that mean there is both a + and - wire inside a mono guitar cable? Or does electricity flow back to the amp/interface/mixer through the ground (the shielding)?

Specifically I'm wondering about a piezo or perhaps some other setup involving a small battery in which I can trigger impulses to flow into my recording interface, and I'm wondering how I need to connect it to the cable. Same thing as a drum trigger, except that my application will be more customized and require me to wire it up myself.

Answer (score 2):

A mono guitar cable (shown lower) has *two conductors*

And I quote from [here](http://www.gollihurmusic.com/faq/51-CABLES_MONO_AND_STEREO_TRS.html):

> The cable at the bottom of the graphic is a "standard" 1/4" instrument cable. It has two conductors (1 and 2), separated by an isolating ring (i) so that they don't contact each other. The TIP (1) carries the "hot" or positive audio signal; the SLEEVE (2) is the ground or negative audio signal.

[image]

The shield does just that, it shields the inner conductors from noise from stray electric fields (like radios, cellphones and the 60Hz hum from AC Mains) If you want to get a analog voltage waveform 'into your equipment", generate a positive voltage on the (1). Every voltage needs to be referenced from something else to be meaningful, most people use ground or near 0V for a reference. So for the return current or ground in your circuit, connect it with (2)

Answer (score 2):

*Or does electricity flow back to the amp/interface/mixer through the ground (the shielding)?*

This is exactly what happens. The shield completes the circuit through which your signal *current* flows. When looking at *voltage*s, the shield is supposed to stay at zero volts as closely as possible, while the signal voltage is developed at the inner conductor, across the source (guitar) and sink (amp) impedances.

[image]

Note how the tips are connected at the source and sink, and therefore required to be at the same voltage referred to ground. Also note how the shield ties the "lower ends" together, requiring them to remain at 0 V at all times.

Look at how the circuit is completed from the source through the amp's input impedance and back through the shield. Kirchhoff (KCL) tells you that the current in the inner connector must be equal to the current in the shield at any time.

Of cource, in a less-than-ideal world, the impedance of both the inner conductor and the shield will be a bit bigger than zero Ohms. This explains hum, and it also explains why differential signalling over a 3-conductor-cable (two inner connectors, one shield) works better:

[image]

Any signal current is carried through the "+" and "-" wires, and the shield will be connected such that it, well... shields, but carries no relevant signal current. The receiver (amp) "looks" at the voltage between "+" and "-" and doesn't care much about any noise current on the shield. In the most simple case, you can look at a configuration where the shield is unconnected at one of the two ends.

You can argue that the picture does not show true differential signalling, because the "-" end is connected to ground, but still, the receiver does look at the difference (voltage) betweed "+" and "-". With true differential signalling, "+" and "-" would be equal in magnitude, but opposite in phase, with regard to ground. Please excuse this simplification, but the purpose of my answer was explaining the dual use of the shield as both the reference and the shield - not so much the details of differential signals.